# How to send Push Notification with emoji via Firebase Console?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I'm trying to send a push notification with Emoji in my Firebase Console. But it did not works well, because the content display in my Android Device like String.

I alreay tryed to sendo like this way

```
<U+1F642>
```

and this

```
"\U1F44D"
```

and this

```
\\U1F44D
```

but anynone works.

Can you help me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried just cop/paste the emoji into the Firebase console notification text field? Search for emojis here http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html, copy from the Browser column the one you want to send and just paste it.

Comment: If you're having problems working with the Firebase console, please send the exact steps that you take that don't work the way you expect to Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support